# Появились вопросы после регистрации в Google Dev

Tags: android, google-play

1. Можно ли мне выпускать обновления приложения с обновленной иконкой?
2. Можно ли мне выпускать обновления не меняя версии приложения?
3. Можно ли выпустить обновление,, которое не содержит package, хотя прошлая версия содержала?
4. Как правильно писать нововведения?
5. Могу ли я выпустить обновление, в котором полностью другая структура кода?
6. а авторское право, могут забанить аккаунт?
7. Я взял исходники платного приложения с code canyon бесплатно. переделал под себя и выложил в play market, что будет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) да
2) "официальную" версию можно не менять. "Неофициальную" (см. в gralde) каждый раз нужно увеличивать
3) любой обновленный apk должен иметь тот же package, что и начальный. Без АПК можно менять любую инфу/картинки
4) не понял вопроса
5) да, хоть другое приложение. Главное - такой же package
6) первый раз предупредят: "подтвердите авторские права" и не опубликуют. В дальнейшем грозят забанить. Дальше первого предупреждения не пробовал)
7) не знаю, если авторы/игроки не возмутятся, то по идее - ничего

Comment: на хабре есть история как приложение убрали из-за описания обновления, но как правильно писать обновления они не написали